# Run a function inside of Stream.map() in Java?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I want to map through an array of strings, and if one of them contains x for example, do something, however, I can't figure out how.
If someone could help me, that would be appreaciated.
Btw, here is an example code:

```
public static void test(String s) {
    if (s.contains("h")) {
        System.out.println("Yes");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No");
    }

    String example = Arrays.stream(example)
        .map(s -> {
            test(s);
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .toString();
}
```

Comment: Function from `map` should return something. In `test(String)` change `System.out.println` with `return` and instead of `void` return type, change in `String`.

Comment: A better interface to `test` is a `Predicate` and that can be used within a `filter`.

Comment: I sense an XY Problem here. Can you be *specific* about what is in the arrays and what you want to do with it, rather than generalize? The above code is not a proper way to use `Stream.map` and is better left as a simple loop.

Comment: Split it into two parts: `Arrays.stream(exmaple).forEach(YourClass::test);`, then `Arrays.stream(exmaple).collect(toList()).toString();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You cannot use the same name for the output `String` and an array from which a stream is created (`example`). Use `String[] input = {"hello", "world"};` and then stream that `String example = Arrays.stream(input)...`
2. The `map` method expects a `Function<T,R>`. The method `void test(String s)` is not compatible with it because of its return type. It should either return `String` or don't use `map` at all.
3. You want many things at once and mix them up. Do you want to get the results and then print them out? Or do you want to print out each result individually and not collect anything at all? Or both - immediate print out and collecting them?

The following snippet contains all the cases you might want:

```
public static String test(String s) {
    return s.contains("h") ? "Yes" : "No";
}
```

```
String[] input = {"hello", "world"};

String example = Arrays.stream(input)  // Streaming "hello" and "world"
    .map(s -> test(s))                 // Converting each word to a result ("Yes" or "No")
    .peek(s -> System.out.println(s))  // Printing the result out immediatelly
    .collect(Collectors.toList())      // Collecting to List<String>
    .toString();

System.out.println(example);       // Prints [Yes, No]
```

Few notes:

- `map(s -> test(s))` shall be rewritten using a method reference: `map(YourClass::test)`
- `peek(s -> System.out.println(s))` shall be rewritten as well: (`peek(System.out::println)`
- A better way of collecting to a `String` is `collect(Collectors.joining(", "))` that results in:

  - `Yes, No`

Comment: Thank you, you saved me! I also know I am late, but still, I wanted to thank you!